# Pandas dataframe: how to apply describe() to each group and add to new columns?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

df:

```
name score
A      1
A      2
A      3
A      4
A      5
B      2
B      4
B      6 
B      8
```

Want to get the following new dataframe in the form of below:

```
   name count mean std min 25% 50% 75% max
    A     5    3    .. ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
    B     4    5    .. ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
```

How to exctract the information from df.describe() and reformat it?
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Define some data

```
In[1]:
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """
name score
A      1
A      2
A      3
A      4
A      5
B      2
B      4
B      6
B      8
    """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\s+')
print(df)
```

.

```
Out[1]:
  name  score
0    A      1
1    A      2
2    A      3
3    A      4
4    A      5
5    B      2
6    B      4
7    B      6
8    B      8
```

#### Solution

A nice approach to this problem uses a generator expression (see footnote) to allow `pd.DataFrame()` to iterate over the results of `groupby`, and construct the summary stats dataframe on the fly:

```
In[2]:
df2 = pd.DataFrame(group.describe().rename(columns={'score':name}).squeeze()
                         for name, group in df.groupby('name'))

print(df2)
```

.

```
Out[2]:
   count  mean       std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
A      5     3  1.581139    1  2.0    3  4.0    5
B      4     5  2.581989    2  3.5    5  6.5    8
```

Here the `squeeze` function is squeezing out a dimension, to convert the one-column group summary stats `Dataframe` into a `Series`.

*Footnote*: A generator expression has the form `my_function(a) for a in iterator`,  or if `iterator` gives us back two-element `tuples`, as in the case of `groupby`:  `my_function(a,b) for a,b in iterator`

Comment: I get an error - df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\s+')
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str  @Pedro M Duarte

Answer (score 55):

there is even a shorter one :)

```
print df.groupby('name').describe().unstack(1)
```

> Nothing beats one-liner:
>
> In [145]:
>
> print df.groupby('name').describe().reset_index().pivot(index='name',
>   values='score', columns='level_1')

Comment: print df.groupby('name').describe().unstack(1).reset_index() is useful

Comment: `df.groupby('name').describe().unstack(1).reset_index().pivot(index='name', values=0, columns='level_1')` would give you a better view.

Answer (score 18):

use code

```
df.groupby('name').describe()
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Nothing beats one-liner:

```
In [145]:

print df.groupby('name').describe().reset_index().pivot(index='name', values='score', columns='level_1')

level_1  25%  50%  75%  count  max  mean  min       std
name                                                   
A        2.0    3  4.0      5    5     3    1  1.581139
B        3.5    5  6.5      4    8     5    2  2.581989
```

Answer (score 8):

Table is stored in dataframe named `df`

```
df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),delimiter='\s+')
```

Just specify column name and `describe` give you required output. In this way you calculate w.r.t any column

```
df.groupby('name')['score'].describe()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

data = """
name score
A      1
A      2
A      3
A      4
A      5
B      2
B      4
B      6
B      8
    """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\s+')

df2 = df.groupby('name').describe().reset_index().T.drop('name')
arr = np.array(df2).reshape((4,8))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr[1:], index=['name','A','B'])

print(df2)
```

That will give you df2 as:

```
              0     1        2    3    4    5    6    7
    name  count  mean      std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
    A         5     3  1.58114    1    2    3    4    5
    B         4     5  2.58199    2  3.5    5  6.5    8
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I managed to get what you wanted but it doesn't scale very well.

```
import pandas as pd

name = ['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b']
score = [1,2,3,4,5,2,4,6,8]

d = pd.DataFrame(zip(name,score), columns=['Name','Score'])
d = d.groupby('Name').describe()
d = d.reset_index()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(zip(d.level_1[8:], list(d.Score)[:8], list(d.Score)[8:]), columns = ['Name','A','B']).T

print df2

          0     1         2    3    4    5    6    7
Name  count  mean       std  min  25%  50%  75%  max
A         5     3  1.581139    1    2    3    4    5
B         4     5  2.581989    2  3.5    5  6.5    8
```