# How to apply scipy.stats.describe to each group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy, statistics

I would appreciate if you could let me know how to apply `scipy.stats.describe` to calculate summary statistics by group. My data (`TrainSet`) is like this:

```
Financial Distress  x1       x2      x3
0                   1.28    0.02    0.87
0                   1.27    0.01    0.82
0                   1.05    -0.06   0.92
1                   1.11    -0.02   0.86
0                   1.06    0.11    0.81
0                   1.06    0.08    0.88
1                   0.87    -0.03   0.79
```

I want to compute the summary statistics by "Financial Distress". I mean something like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575587/pandas-dataframe-how-to-apply-describe-to-each-group-and-add-to-new-columns) but via `scipy.stats.describe` because I need skewness and kurtosis for x1, x2, and x3 by group. However, my code doesn't provide the statistics by group.

```
    desc=dict()
    for col in TrainSet.columns:
        if [TrainSet["Financial Distress"]==0]:
            desc[col] = describe(TrainSet[col]())
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(desc, orient='index')
            df.to_csv("Descriptive Statistics3.csv")
```

In fact, I need something like this:

```
Group                                    0                                                                 1                       
statistics          nobs    minmax       mean   variance    skewness    kurtosis    nobs    minmax       mean   variance    skewness    kurtosis
Financial Distress  2569    (0, 1)        0.0     0.0         4.9           22.1    50      (0, 1)        0.0     0.0         2.9         22.1
x1                  2569    (0.1, 38)     1.4     1.7        16.5           399.9   50      (-3.6, 3.8)    0.3    0.1         0.5         21.8
x2                  2569    (-0.2, 0.7)  0.1      0.0         1.0           1.8     50      (-0.3, 0.7)    0.1    0.0         0.9         1.2
x3                  2569    (0.1, 0.9)   0.6      0.0        -0.5           -0.2    50      (0.1, 0.9)     0.6    0.0        -0.6         -0.3
x4                  2569    (5.3, 6.3)    0.9     0.3         3.2           19.7    50      (-26, 38)     14.0   12.0        15.1         26.5
x5                  2569    (-0.2, 0.8)   0.2     0.0         0.8            1.4    50      (0.3, 0.9)     0.4    0.0        0.5          -0.3
```

Or

```
            nobs     minmax     mean       variance     skewness    kurtosis                            
x1  0        5  (1.05, 1.28)    1.144      0.01433  4.073221e-01    -1.825477                               
    1        2  (0.87, 1.11)    0.990      0.02880  1.380350e-15    -2.000000                               

x2  0        5   (-0.06, 0.11)    0.032      0.00437 -1.992376e-01    -1.130951                             
    1        2  (-0.03, -0.02)   -0.025      0.00005  1.058791e-15    -2.000000                             

x3  0        5  (0.81, 0.92)    0.860      0.00205  1.084093e-01    -1.368531                           
    1        2  (0.79, 0.86)    0.825      0.00245  4.820432e-15    -2.000000
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to describe 3 series independently by group, it seems you'll need 3 dataframes. You can construct these dataframes and then concatenate them:

```
from scipy.stats import describe

grouper = df.groupby('FinancialDistress')

variables = df.columns[1:]

res = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(describe(g[x]) for _, g in grouper)\
                   .reset_index().assign(cat=x).set_index(['cat', 'index']) \
                 for x in variables], axis=0)

print(res)

           nobs          minmax   mean  variance      skewness  kurtosis
cat index                                                               
x1  0         5    (1.05, 1.28)  1.144   0.01433  4.073221e-01 -1.825477
    1         2    (0.87, 1.11)  0.990   0.02880  1.380350e-15 -2.000000
x2  0         5   (-0.06, 0.11)  0.032   0.00437 -1.992376e-01 -1.130951
    1         2  (-0.03, -0.02) -0.025   0.00005  1.058791e-15 -2.000000
x3  0         5    (0.81, 0.92)  0.860   0.00205  1.084093e-01 -1.368531
    1         2    (0.79, 0.86)  0.825   0.00245  4.820432e-15 -2.000000
```